# When i transform an object, the previous key frame changes as well

Tags: animation, keyframes

The whole object moves across all key frames. I was just wanting to change the position at each key frame.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that first sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift your playhead to the keyframe, transform the object, hover your cursor over the 3D viewport, press "i" on your keyboard, and click "Location." To enable automatic keyframing, you can click [image: the red dot icon in the timeline editor.] in the timeline editor.